# How to unsubscribe from toppic in Rabbit Mq?

Tags: rabbitmq

Sa we had subscribed to `e.*.*` we want to unsubscribe from `e.exact.*` topic. is there any way to do such thing? Any RabbitMQ plugin that would provide subscribe to `e.!exact.*`?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that with a regular topic exchange.  I am not aware of one that allows it but there maybe something out there

Alternatively:

1) filter according to that field of the routing key once the message has been received

2) bind to all binding keys that are not `e.exact.*`

3) change the routing key format to better allow you to select only the keys that you want

As a rule I prefer to select what I want rather than take everything that isnt X.

if you now add a key `e.y.*` that you also don't want you need to have a way to select `e.(!Exact && !y).*`

Comment: If you provide a little more info perhaps I can suggest something that can work